# Dynamic Tabs inside TabBar Widget rather than static ones

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tabbar

**Context:** I have the current design -shown in a screenshot below -  where I implemented the `Tab`s statically,

[image: Tab Bars]

**Question:** How can we create `Tab`s on the fly with dynamic values from a server?

For example, a server sends more than 5 `Tab`s.

My current implementation  contains an AppBar that supports a `TabBar` with Tabs as a list of Widgets

Here's the code snippet for the tab bar:

```
 bottom: TabBar(
        labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        indicatorColor: kDarkColor,
        labelColor: kDarkColor,
        indicatorWeight: 2,
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
        isScrollable: true,
        tabs: [
          Tab(child: Text('Timeline.mostPopularTab'.tr())),
          Tab(child: Text('Timeline.menTab'.tr())),
          Tab(child: Text('Timeline.womenTab'.tr())),
          Tab(child: Text('Timeline.kidsTab'.tr())),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TabBar(
tabs: _tabsListFromServer.map((serverTab) => Tab(child: Text(serverTab.title))).toList(),
)
```